# Calculating the line thickness when drawing

Tags: java, events, mouse, frame

I can draw lines, but the thickness is constant. I need to change the thickness when I press a button. In this example pressing 'w' will increase the thickness and pressing 'q' will decrease the thickness.

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

import sun.swing.SwingUtilities2;

public class draw extends Applet {

    boolean isBlack = true;
    Point startPoint;
    Point points[];
    int numPoints;
    boolean drawing;
    int n = 0;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        startPoint = new Point(0, 0);
        points = new Point[10000];
        drawing = false;
        resize(300, 400);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        if (n == 0) {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
        }
        if (n == 1) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
        }
        if (n == 2) {
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
        }
        if (n == 3) {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
        }

        int oldX = startPoint.x;
        int oldY = startPoint.y;
        for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i) {
            g.drawLine(oldX, oldY, points[i].x, points[i].y);
            oldX = points[i].x;
            oldY = points[i].y;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(Event evt, int key) {
        char keyChar = (char) key;

        if (keyChar == 'w') {
            n++;
            if (n > 3) {
                n = 0;
            }
        }
        if (keyChar == 'q') {
            n--;
            if (n < 0) {
                n = 3;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseDown(Event evt, int x, int y) {

        if (!drawing) {
            startPoint.x = x;
            startPoint.y = y;
        }
        drawing = !drawing;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMove(Event evt, int x, int y) {
        if ((drawing) && (numPoints < 10000)) {
            points[numPoints] = new Point(x, y);
            ++numPoints;
            repaint();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

But I can't *calculate* the thickness of the line, how would I do that?

Comment: Why are you using AWT? That technology is about 12 years outdated. What Java version are you using?

Comment: Hi there! I edited your title as it was broad and made your question less obvious, so now people will know exactly what you're asking about when they click the link. Titles are important for allowing people to understand exactly what you're asking about so try to make them as direct as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Graphics2D package:

```
Graphics2D g2 = SwingUtilities2.getGraphics2D(g);
g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(n));
g2.drawLine(oldX, oldY, points[i].x, points[i].y);
```

I think that's is all you need. It's been awhile since I've worked with it.